# Assigning the value of a variable to a defined Name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a worksheet defined name "Token" and I need it to refer to the value of Access_Token Variable. Lets say Access_Token = "This is a Token".

Then I would like the Defined Name to be set to "This is a Token".
I have tried the following code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Token", RefersTo:=Access_Token
```

I can do it as follows:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Token", RefersTo:="=This is a Token"
```

But I am getting "Runtime 1004 Error".

Does anyone know the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return value from a named range or assign value like that

```
Sub ReturnValueFromNamedRange()
    MsgBox Replace(Replace(ThisWorkbook.Names("MyNamedRange").Value, "=", vbNullString), Chr(34), vbNullString)
End Sub

Sub AssignValueToNamedRange()
    ThisWorkbook.Names("MyNamedRange").Value = "YasserKhalil"
End Sub

Sub AssignValueToNamedRangeByVariable()
    Dim Access_Token As String
    Access_Token = "This Is A Token"
    ThisWorkbook.Names("MyNamedRange").Value = Access_Token
End Sub
```

To create named range

```
Sub CreateNamedRangeAndAssignValue()
    Dim Access_Token As String
    Access_Token = "This Is A Token"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Token", RefersToR1C1:="=""" & Access_Token & """"
End Sub
```

And if you need to check if the named range exists or not and if exists create it

```
Sub CheckIfNamedRangeExistsCreateIfNot()
    Dim obj As Object, sName As String, sValue As String
    sName = "Token"
    sValue = "This Is A Token"
    On Error Resume Next
        Set obj = ThisWorkbook.Names(sName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not obj Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Named Range Exists And Its Value = " & Replace(Replace(ThisWorkbook.Names(sName).Value, "=", vbNullString), Chr(34), vbNullString), 64
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=sName, RefersToR1C1:="=""" & sValue & """"
        MsgBox "Named Range Created", 64
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, i can do that for a named range, as you suggest, however what i really want to do is have VBA create a Defined Name and assign it a value. No ranges involved. I can do that through the user interface, however i would like to do it via VBA.

Comment: Hi Yasser. you are correct and have answered my question. and actually you do not need to check if a name exists as it will be created or reassigned.

Comment: Yes I noticed that.. but liked to include to be able to have the flexibility if it already exists and have a value to make the user decide another decision.

Comment: Sub CreateDefinedName()
Dim Access_Token As String

Access_Token = "This is a token"
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Access_Token", RefersToR1C1:="=""" & Access_Token & """"

End Sub

Comment: Yes this will work with no problem. Hope this answer helps you. Regards